# How to open System wifi setting using a python 3 code

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, wifi

for running this script behind when a request is done or on clicking a button in a desktop application this file runs in the background and opens the system wifi setting in windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the winwifi: https://github.com/changyuheng/winwifi.py

Installation:

```
pip install winwifi
```

Now you could try connecting a known wifi:

```
import winwifi
winwifi.WinWiFi.connect('ssid_or_name_of_the_router')
```